# Http Filter in Node.js

Tags: node.js

I want to filter http requests and allow only calls from certain domains which I'm interested in. Is it possible to do it as part of App Configuration? - Any libraries available for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`req.connection.remoteAddress` will have the IP address of the system making the request; you can do a reverse DNS lookup on it and match against the returned domains. If you're using express or connect you can write a middleware function to do this.